# How to highlight the button when it is pressed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two charts and two buttons to switch between them.

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="DIM1">Dimension_1</button>
  <button id="DIM2">Dimension_2</button>
</div
```

I want to highlight the button related to the choosen dataset. Also I need to highlight first one initially because the first dataset is displayed at the beginning.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/v72kLebe/

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight" ? Should it look like it is pressed ?

Comment: Use radiobuttons instead of buttons, so you can style accordingly using the `:checked` pseudoclass.

Comment: I mean the different button style, when it is pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a class named "active_btn" to css file
add it to the first button
when a button is clicked, remove class active_btn of all other button, and add it to the current button.

See code snippet to understand

```js
var dataset = [681, 602, 613, 648, 654, 669, 688, 701, 697, 686, 684, 675, 742, 655, 662, 709, 709, 718, 739];
  
  //Width and height
  var w = 620;
  var h = 320;
  var bottomPadding = 40;
    var topPadding = 10;
  var barPadding = 5;
  var barWidth = d3.round(w / dataset.length);

  //Localize numbers, dates, currencies
  var ru_BY = {
   "decimal": ",",
   "thousands": "\xa0",
   "grouping": [3],
   "currency": ["", " Br"],
   "dateTime": "%A, %e %B %Y г. %X",
   "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
   "time": "%H:%M:%S",
   "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
   "days": ["воскресенье", "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота"],
   "shortDays": ["вс", "пн", "вт", "ср", "чт", "пт", "сб"],
   "months": ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
   "shortMonths": ["янв", "фев", "мар", "апр", "май", "июн", "июл", "авг", "сен", "окт", "ноя", "дек"]
  };

  //Store locale object
  var RU = d3.locale(ru_BY);

  //Create scale function for bar height
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
        .rangeRound([bottomPadding, h - topPadding - bottomPadding]);

  //Define x axis
  var minDate = new Date(2014, 11, 1),
   maxDate = new Date(2016, 5, 1);

  var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([minDate, maxDate])
        .range([(barWidth - barPadding) / 2, barWidth * (dataset.length - 1) + (barWidth - barPadding) / 2]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
              //Specify the frequency of ticks
              .ticks(d3.time.months, 1)
              //Specify size of ticks, by default 6
              .tickSize(0)
              .tickFormat(RU.timeFormat("%b %Y"));
  
  //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h);
  
  //Create rectangles
  svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
       return i * barWidth;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d) - bottomPadding;
   })
   .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
   .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d);
   })
   .attr("fill", "red")
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        var tickDate = d3.select(d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]).data()[0];
        console.log (tickDate);
        var formatDate = RU.timeFormat("%B %Y");
        var tooltipDate = formatDate(tickDate);
       //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3. select(this). attr("x")) + ((barWidth - barPadding) / 2);
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3. select(this). attr("y")) / 2 + h / 2;
        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip" )
         .style("left" , xPosition + "px")
          .style("top" , yPosition + "px")
          .select("#value")
          .text(d + " Br");
    d3.select("#tooltip" )
          .select("#label")
          .text(tooltipDate);
    //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip" ).
         classed("hidden" , false);
    d3.select(this)
         .attr("fill", "orange");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
       //Hide the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip")
         .classed("hidden" , true);
       d3.select(this)
         .transition()
          .duration(150)
         .attr("fill", "red");
      });

  //Create text
  svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
    return d;
   })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
       return i * barWidth + (barWidth - barPadding) / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d) + 14 - bottomPadding;
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white")
      .style("pointer-events", "none");

  //Add x axis
  svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - bottomPadding) + ")")
     .call(xAxis)
       .selectAll(".tick text")
       .call(wrap, 40);
       
    function wrap(text, width) {
     text.each(function() { 
       var text = d3.select(this), 
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(), 
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, 
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")), 
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) { 
      line.push(word); 
      tspan.text(line.join(" ")); 
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function transition(dataset, dimension) {
 //Update scale domain
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset)]);
  //Update all rects
  svg.selectAll("rect")
     .data(dataset)
     .transition(150)
     .attr("y", function(d) {
       return h - yScale(d) - bottomPadding;
     })
     .attr("height", function(d) {
       return yScale(d);
     })
     .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
       return dimension === " DIM1" ? "red" : "blue";
     });
  svg.selectAll("rect")
     .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
       var tickDate = d3.select(d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]).data()[0];
        var formatDate = RU.timeFormat("%B %Y");
        var tooltipDate = formatDate(tickDate);
       //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3. select(this). attr("x")) + ((barWidth - barPadding) / 2);
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3. select(this). attr("y")) / 2 + h / 2;
        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip" )
         .style("left" , xPosition + "px")
          .style("top" , yPosition + "px")
          .select("#value")
          .text(d + dimension);          
    d3.select("#tooltip" )
          .select("#label")
          .text(tooltipDate);
    //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip" )
          .classed("hidden" , false);
    d3.select(this)
         .attr("fill", "orange");
     })
     .on("mouseout", function(d) {
       //Hide the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip")
         .classed("hidden" , true);
       d3.select(this)
         .transition()
          .duration(150)
         .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return dimension === " DIM1" ? "red" : "blue"; } );
      });
  //Update all labels
 svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
     .transition(150)
   .text(function(d) {
     return d;
   })
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return i * barWidth + (barWidth - barPadding) / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d) + 14 - bottomPadding;
   });
}

d3.select("#DIM1")
    .on("click", function() {
        //New values for dataset
        var dataset = [681, 602, 613, 648, 654, 669, 688, 701, 697, 686, 684, 675, 742, 655, 662, 709, 709, 718, 739];
        transition(dataset, " DIM1")
     });
     
d3.select("#DIM2")
    .on("click", function() {
        //New values for dataset
        var dataset = [619, 412, 408, 438, 463, 474, 449, 458, 415, 389, 409, 379, 412, 345, 307, 343, 361, 369, 371];
        transition(dataset, " DIM2")
     });
     
$('.hightlight_btn').click(function(){
 $('.hightlight_btn').removeClass('active_btn');
 $(this).addClass('active_btn');
});
```

```css
.axis path,
   .axis line {
    fill: none;
    /* stroke: black; */
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }
   
   .axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
   }
      
      #tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    pointer-events: none;
   }
   
   #tooltip.hidden {
    display: none;
   }
   
   #tooltip p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
   }
      
      .buttons {
        text-align: center;
        width: 620px;
      }
      
      .active_btn {
        background-color: red;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
  <p><strong><span id="label">month</span></strong></p>
  <p><span id="value">100</span></p>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="DIM1" class="hightlight_btn active_btn">Dimension_1</button>
  <button id="DIM2" class="hightlight_btn">Dimension_2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified the bottom part of your script:

```
d3.select("#DIM1")
    .on("click", function() {
        //New values for dataset
        var dataset = [681, 602, 613, 648, 654, 669, 688, 701, 697, 686, 684, 675, 742, 655, 662, 709, 709, 718, 739];

        d3.select('#DIM2').style('background-color', 'initial');
        d3.select(this).style('background-color', '#99ccee');

        transition(dataset, " DIM1")
     });

d3.select("#DIM2")
    .on("click", function() {
        //New values for dataset
        var dataset = [619, 412, 408, 438, 463, 474, 449, 458, 415, 389, 409, 379, 412, 345, 307, 343, 361, 369, 371];

        d3.select('#DIM1').style('background-color', 'initial');
        d3.select(this).style('background-color', '#99ccee');

        transition(dataset, " DIM2")
     });
```

On 'Click' event I just select the button and set the background-color property, and then select the other button and reset the background-color property.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably toggle a class on the buttons when they're clicked. Something like this:

```
.buttons .active {
   background: red;
}
```

(You would of course style this appropriately, not just making it red...)

And then something like this, assuming you have access to Jquery:

```
d3.select("#DIM1")
.on("click", function() {

    $('.buttons button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

    //New values for dataset
    var dataset = [681, 602, 613, 648, 654, 669, 688, 701, 697, 686, 684, 675, 742, 655, 662, 709, 709, 718, 739];
    transition(dataset, " DIM1")
 });

d3.select("#DIM2")
    .on("click", function() {

    $('.buttons button').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

        //New values for dataset
        var dataset = [619, 412, 408, 438, 463, 474, 449, 458, 415, 389, 409, 379, 412, 345, 307, 343, 361, 369, 371];
        transition(dataset, " DIM2")
     });
```

If you do not wish to use JQuery here's a d3.js approach:

```
d3.select("#DIM1")
.on("click", function() {
    d3.select("#DIM1").attr('class', 'active');
  d3.select("#DIM2").attr('class', '');
    //New values for dataset
    var dataset = [681, 602, 613, 648, 654, 669, 688, 701, 697, 686, 684, 675, 742, 655, 662, 709, 709, 718, 739];
    transition(dataset, " DIM1")
 });

d3.select("#DIM2")
    .on("click", function() {
      d3.select("#DIM2").attr('class', 'active');
      d3.select("#DIM1").attr('class', '');
        //New values for dataset
        var dataset = [619, 412, 408, 438, 463, 474, 449, 458, 415, 389, 409, 379, 412, 345, 307, 343, 361, 369, 371];
        transition(dataset, " DIM2")
     });
```